# Probability of a random outcome given a sample size

Tags: probability, distributions, bayesian, sample

Say you gave an IQ test to a random sample of $n$ people, but instead of having the actual test results, you have only the normalized data for this sample (mean=0, $\sigma$=1).

What is the probability that person $A$ is in the top 5% of the total population (1.64 standard deviations above mean), given that their normalized IQ score $S$ is $X$ standard deviations above the sample mean?

I'm approaching that question from a Bayesian perspective (which is new to me), so I define it as:
$$
P(A>1.64 | S=X)= \frac{P(S=X|A>1.64) \times 0.05}{P(S=X|A>1.64) \times 0.05 + P(S=X|A<1.64) \times 0.95}
$$

The probabilities I'm after are: $P(S=X|A>1.64)$ and $P(S=X|A<1.64)$.

I'm trying to use frequentist statistics to determine probability of a sampling error in the sample population. For example:

For $X>1.64$, $P(S=X|A<1.64) = $ probability that the sample mean $x$ would be inflated by $X-1.64$, or the sample standard deviation would be dampened by $X-1.64$.

Is this the right approach? And if so, how would you determine the same probability for $X<1.64$?

Here are my calculations for the probability of the mean and standard deviation being wrong:

mean: 
$$
\mu = X - 1.64, x = 0, \sigma=1 \\
z = \frac{x - \mu}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}} \\
z = \frac{1.64 - X}{n^\frac{1}{2}}
$$

standard deviation:
$$
df = n - 1, \sigma = 1.64 - X, s = 1 \\
z = \frac{(n-1) \times s^2}{\sigma^2} \\
z = \frac{n - 1}{(1.64 - X)^2}
$$

Comment: The answer must depend on the distribution of IQ scores in the population, which presumably you don't know (otherwise why are you sampling?). If you made a *minor* change and asked "what is the chance that the $q$th percentile of the sample is in the highest $5$% of the population"--or, more simply, "what is the chance that the $r$th highest out of an iid sample of $n$ would be in the highest $5$% of the population"--this question would have a universal (distribution-independent) answer.

Comment: @whuber I was assuming that the IQ scores was normally distributed. If the question were changed per your suggestion, "what is the chance that the $r$th highest out of an iid sample of $n$ is in the highest $5\%$ of the population?", how would you set up the probability?

Comment: The chance that any individual subject in the sample is in the highest $5\%$ is, of course, $.05$. This is a Binomial random variable, whence the chance that at least $r$ subjects are in the highest $5\%$ is given by the (complementary) CDF of a Binomial distribution with size $n$ and probability $5\%$.